# failed to read the project description file in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

I am new to android.While checking out a code from SVN , I face this issue:

```
     Checkout operation for 
    'https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/SamplePjt/trunk/Android/SamplePjtv1.0/SamplePjt' failed.
     Failed to read the project description file (.project) for 'SamplePjt'.  The file has been changed on disk, and it now contains invalid information.  The project will not function properly until the description file is restored to a valid state.
```

Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: you use eclipse to checkout the SVN?

Comment: @nayoso yes I used eclipse to checkout the SVN

Comment: @nayoso I even tried with SMARTSVN and checkout the code then tried importing the code to workspace still the same error exists